# Sending data from a TCP Client (C) to a server (C#/WinForms)

Tags: c#, c, winforms, sockets, tcp

I'm working with a WiFi module written in C that connects to a TCP server written in C++/WinAPI. At the moment, I'm trying to write up some documentation on the protocol being used, as none currently exists. In order to make this a bit easier, I've written a simple application in C#/WinForms in order to more easily send and read received packets.

When working with the existing server, the module connects and then sends a packet with a serial number (i.e. #12345) as a byte array. A green LED also begins blinking when connected to the socket.

When using my new testing server, the server detects that the client is connected (socket.Connected == true), then StreamReader.ReadLine() begins receiving endless nulls. The LED on the client also does not blink green, so it looks as though the client is not connected to the socket.

I don't have a ton of experience with TCP/IP, can anyone see any flaws with the route I'm taking or think of any possible reason why the client end isn't detecting the connection/ sending it's serial number, while the server seems to be working just fine? Thanks in advance for any input.

EDIT: 
Here is some of the state machine the module uses to connect to the server..

```
switch(TransmitState)
{
    case CHECK_POLLTIME:
        if(PollCounter >= Device.MinutesPerPoll)    
        {
            PollCounter = 0;
            TransmitState++;    // initiate server communications
        }
        break;

    case LOAD_SOCKET:

        if(AppConfig.IsLinked != LINKED) break;


        // Connect a socket to the remote TCP server
        if(!TCPIsConnected(socket))
        socket= TCPOpen(server_ip, server_port);


        TransmitState++;
        Timer = TickGet();
        break;

    case POLL_SERVER:
        // Wait for the remote server to accept our connection request
        if(!TCPIsConnected(socket))
        {
            // Time out if too much time is spent in this state
            if(TickGet()-Timer > 5*TICK_SECOND)
            {
                // Close the socket so it can be used by other modules
                TransmitState = SM_DISCONNECT;
            }
            break;
        }

        Timer = TickGet();

        if(Bootloader)
            break;

        // Make certain the socket can be written to


        if(U2Tx.count != 0) break;

        // Place the application protocol data into the transmit buffer. 

        //packet needs to include UART commands to get through
        TCPBuffer[0] = 0x1B;    //ESC
        TCPBuffer[1] = 'Z';
        TCPBuffer[2] = AppConfig.ConnectionID;

        TCPBuffer[3] = '0';
        TCPBuffer[4] = '0';
        TCPBuffer[5] = '0';
        TCPBuffer[6] = '6';



        TCPBuffer[7] = '#'; // represents serial number
        TCPBuffer[8] = Device.Serial[0];
        TCPBuffer[9] = Device.Serial[1];
        TCPBuffer[10] = Device.Serial[2];
        TCPBuffer[11] = Device.Serial[3];
        TCPBuffer[12] = Device.Serial[4];


        WF_TxBlock(TCPBuffer, 13);


        TransmitState++;
        break;

    case PROCESS_RESPONSE:
```

...

Comment: Most likely, client expects the server to send something back?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it looks like the module code connects the socket (socket = TCPOpen(server_ip, server_port), checks that the socket is connected, and then sends the serial number. It doesn't seem to check for anything when connecting before sending the serial number.

Comment: How do you know this? Did you use a network traffic sniffer to verify this?

Comment: You should try wireshark (or similar) with the original setup. Capture all the network traffic and then try to solve the traffic data.

Comment: I went through the actual code, there's a state machine that attempts to connect to the socket then polls the server. I have a decent idea of how the module works, however quite a bit of the code is hard to follow and I can't use a debugger with the module, which is why I'm trying to set this up. I'll update the original question to include some of the state machine.